# Dask Cluster/Kernel Restarts after trying to Compute Dataframe Column

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-computing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to plot a boxplot for a single column in a Dask Dataframe. I realized in order to plot the graph, the data needs to be a pandas df. I try to run `df['Y'].compute()` but everytime I attempt it, the cluster and kernel restart itself with no warning and the df is no longer defined. The issue is, I had just persisted the entire df into memory by doing `df = df.persist()`. So the compute() should be pretty quick since the column is already in-memory.

My cluster specs:

- Workers: 83
- Total threads: 332
- Total memory: 2.24 TiB

---

- Number of partitons: 3132
- Total df GB: 140 GB

Memory space isn't a problem, I have no clue whats wrong. My goal is winsorize the column to eliminate outliers.

Comment: how much memory do you have? 140GB is a lot to load into a single dataframe. note that `df.persist()` is an asyncronous command (dask does not wait until the dataset is fully persisted) so it could be the data isn't yet fully in memory. you could test this theory with `dask.distributed.wait(df)` right after the persist.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have a cluster with 2.24TB of memory. 83 workers. So there should def be enough memory, right? Also, I do wait till the persist is over for exactly that reason, to not overload the task scheduler.

Comment: oh - but compute() brings it into the memory of the client process. so you'd need that much on whichever machine is calling compute(). I think memory is likely the problem :) can you windsorize the data using an approximate quantile algorithm with [`dask.dataframe.Series.quantile`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.quantile.html)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I tried but I get an 'IndexError: tuple index out of range' error :/ which is a result of '.shape[1]' not being able to compute into memory. This sucks.

Comment: We're here to help! But we really can't if you don't show us your code. Dask does have a learning curve, but it's worth it :) Can you ask a question that shows us the code you're using and the error you're encountering?

Comment: generally, cluster computing with larger-than-memory datasets *is hard and will take some getting used to*. dask makes that easier... but don't expect it to be as straightforward as working in memory. don't get discouraged - you're just doing hard things :)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I appreciate the encouragement, definitely needed! I'll post a question and link it below once I post it!

Comment: @user18749759 use the edit modify and modify this question. you don't need to make a new one